# Can KDB publish aggregated OHLC bars at any interval?

Tags: kdb

I apologize if the question isn't relevant I am new to KDB+ and am wondering if kdb+ offered the functionality of publishing aggregated tick data by n interval such that other process can now have this data to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box, though `q` is very powerful for this kind of thing!

You would have to amend `tick.q` to be able to do this. Unfortunately if you're new to q this is file is not going to be a happy read for you :)

By default `tick.q` keeps data in memory for 1 second and then publishes out. If you wanted it to, say, publish every 60 seconds with aggregated data you would

1. Set `-t` to `60000` on the command line when you start the tickerplant process, so that it's timer runs every 60 seconds (else do `\t 60000` directly in the script)
2. Change `.u.pub` to aggregrate the data instead of simply pumping out the table(s) to listeners, something like `0!select max price, min price, first price, last price by sym, time.minute from t`
3. When your listeners subscribe to a tickerplant they request the schema of each table, effectively, first. But your aggregation doesn't look like that schema obviously, so listeners need to be aware of this.

**EDIT**

Having re-read your question, you're asking for aggregation for every `n` rows - if you really want this, then it's best to aggregate in your query rather than get your tickerplant to aggregate and publish. The reason is that it's even more complex than the above to accomplish, since you'd need to keep a count too so that you know when to aggregate.

If memory isn't an issue, keep the raw data and aggregate in your query on the realtime database using `i` as the "row count keeper" and `xbar`, e.g. aggregate for 1000 rows:

```
select Low:min price, High:max price by Bucket:1000 xbar i from
  aTable where sym=`abc, (`time$time) within (09:00;10:00)
```